# How to get the list of all keys from this array of object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to get a list of array of object, which should give me all the keys for the array.

The list should return names of all keys that is : [districtId, districtName,
verified,
unVerified,
verificationPer,
enumeratorPer,
totalRegistered
].

The array of object is here :

```js
 let a =   [{
  "districtId": "2351",
  "districtName": "A",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 2
}, {
  "districtId": "2349",
  "districtName": "A",
  "verified": 1,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 100,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}, {
  "districtId": "2332",
  "districtName": "B",
  "verified": 1,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 4
}, {
  "districtId": "2343",
  "districtName": "C",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}, {
  "districtId": "2302",
  "districtName": "M",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 2
}, {
  "districtId": "2301",
  "districtName": "S",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}]
```

Comment: Object.keys(a[0])

Comment: Will every object in the array have identical keys?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in order to get all keys of one of the items in your array.

```
Object.keys(a[0]));
```

Full working Example:

```js
let a =   [{
  "districtId": "2351",
  "districtName": "A",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 2
}, {
  "districtId": "2349",
  "districtName": "A",
  "verified": 1,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 100,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}, {
  "districtId": "2332",
  "districtName": "B",
  "verified": 1,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 4
}, {
  "districtId": "2343",
  "districtName": "C",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}, {
  "districtId": "2302",
  "districtName": "M",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 2
}, {
  "districtId": "2301",
  "districtName": "S",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}]

console.log(Object.keys(a[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the objects in the array have the same set of keys then you can use `Object.keys(a[0])` else you can iterate through the array and run `Object.keys(a[n])` where n is each iteration.

```js
let a =   [{
  "districtId": "2351",
  "districtName": "A",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 2
}, {
  "districtId": "2349",
  "districtName": "A",
  "verified": 1,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 100,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}, {
  "districtId": "2332",
  "districtName": "B",
  "verified": 1,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 4
}, {
  "districtId": "2343",
  "districtName": "C",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}, {
  "districtId": "2302",
  "districtName": "M",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 2
}, {
  "districtId": "2301",
  "districtName": "S",
  "verified": 0,
  "unVerified": 0,
  "verificationPer": 0,
  "enumeratorPer": 0,
  "totalRegistered": 1
}]

console.log(Object.keys(a[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
const b = a.flatMap(item => Object.keys(item)).filter(onlyUnique)
```

or simply use code below if you are sure that all the keys of objects are the same

```
Object.keys(a[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = data.flatMap(x => Object.keys(x));
console.log(result)
```